# Is there something similar to Google Map Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I really like [Google Map Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/new_map_charts.html), but the maximum size that can be generated is only 420x220 which is small.

Is there any similar service or product? Maybe using Javascript?

[edit]
  Don't you think this is small [map](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,EAF7FE&chs=440x220&cht=t&chco=FFFFFF,FF0000,FFFF00,00FF00&chld=AZCOGAILLANMNVTXUTVT&chd=t:33,22,22,88,22,77,8,22,2,7&chtm=usa) ?
[image]

Comment: Actually, they claim that the maximum size is 600x600.  Is that large enough?

Comment: @Robert: the maximum size is actually 300k pixels total, with a maximum side length of 600px, if I'm reading the documentation correctly (assuming the "300,000 pixels" isn't a typo in the docs). Is that still too small?

Comment: @Matt: That would make it 600x500.

Comment: @Robert I tried it, it doesn't work if it is larger than 440x220

Comment: @Robert: or ~547px square. Point being, 600x600 is larger than the max number of pixels.

Comment: @Mark: this worked just fine for me, at 600x500: http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=map:fixed=-60,0,80,-35&chs=600x500&chld=CA-BC|CN|IT|GR|US-UT&chdl=Vancouver|Beijing|Torino|Athens|Salt+Lake+City&chco=B3BCC0|5781AE|FF0000|FFC726|885E80|518274&chtt=Last+Five+Olympic+Hosts&chm=f2010+Winter,000000,0,0,10&f2008+Summer,000000,0,1,10&f2008+Winter,000000,0,2,10,1,:-5:10&f2004+Summer,000000,0,3,10&f2004+Summer,000000,0,4,10&chma=0,110,0,0

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution using JS and SVG/VML: http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net/

Answer (score 1):

This Google map chart is 600x350 pixels.

[image]

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=map:fixed=-60,0,80,-35&chs=600x350&chld=CA-BC|CN|IT|GR|US-UT&chdl=Vancouver|Beijing|Torino|Athens|Salt+Lake+City&chco=B3BCC0|5781AE|FF0000|FFC726|885E80|518274&chtt=Last+Five+Olympic+Hosts&chm=f2010+Winter,000000,0,0,10|f2008+Summer,000000,0,1,10|f2008+Winter,000000,0,2,10,1,:-5:10|f2004+Summer,000000,0,3,10|f2004+Summer,000000,0,4,10

Comment: Could you post Google Chart link please?

Comment: It's at the bottom of this answer.

Comment: Thanks you just gave me an idea. I can just make it larger using height and width when I embed it with <img> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Raphaël Javascript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/), they have an [example of Australia](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html) that might be helpful.  It's all vector-based so once you get your points set up you can scale the image to be as big as you want.

Comment: To anyone looking at this now, Raphael also have a world map demo: http://raphaeljs.com/world/

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Map Chart we can define any size. Check [Google Chart Library Tutotrial](https://www.studytutorial.in/google-maps-chart-in-javascript-using-google-maps-api-tutorial)

[image]

[image]